# I am looking for an online Japanese dictionary with audio pronunciations

Tags: pronunciation, resources, dictionary

Does anyone know any online Japanese dictionary which provides audio reading?

Comment: I voted to close because this is really barely related to the Japanese language itself, and is answered easily by a [Google search for "japanese dictionary"](http://www.google.com/search?q=japanese+dictionary).

Comment: Usually when one wants to close a question he doesn't answer it :) and a link to meta is good also: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/160/what-should-our-faq-contain/166#166

Comment: OK. I had to scour meta to try and figure where we currently stand on "what are good resources/dictionary" questions, and the consensus is still pretty muddled, so I won't force an immediate close (but feel free to vote for a close if you feel that way)... But I think it should at least be made a Community Wiki. Updating accordingly.

Comment: Why? Pronunciation of a single word by some software isn't going to be *much* helpful to have a nice intonation. And as Japanese basically reads as it's written, I quite doubt this would be useful…

Comment: @Axioplase, "And as Japanese basically reads as it's written". Sure, much more so than English. But Japanese orthography doesn't tell you about pitch. Nor does it tell you about devoiced vowels. Nor does it tell you if a given instance of う is pronounced /u/ or /o/. I can see lots of good reason to have such a dictionary.

Comment: @dainichi: Don't forget rendaku. Then of course there's kanji that have multiple acceptable readings even in the same context, but that one at least is kind of an edge case (-:

Comment: @Dave Should this question be protected? That would prevent new users posting possible spam? Or is it an overkill?

Comment: @Szymon There's no reason people couldn't post new suggestions to what is a very open question. But actually, I thought this had been firmly established as off-topic for the main site. Maybe it should be moved to Meta and/or integrated into the FAQ.

Comment: I agree this should be on meta. I think pronunciation is important enough to warrant a new answer on the meta question for resources, so [I added one here](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1381/3275). If you like it, feel free to add a link to the [overview in the question](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/756/3275). Perhaps it can be closed now? @Dave

Answer (score 9):

It's strange that no one mentioned that [WWWJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1C) provides the audio clips for the reading for all the entries (rintaun only mentioned about the pronunciation hiragana).

In case anyone misses it (I didn't realize the blue button is a play sound button until later), here is where:

[image: play sound button wwwjdic]

Comment: “I didn't realize the blue button is a play sound button until later”  I did not know that.  Thanks!

Comment: *Regarding "audio clips for the reading for all the entries"*... Many many entries do not have the audio clip icon, and some have the icon but the clip is not available e.g. http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1MUJ%E3%81%BB%E3%81%97%E3%82%93

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much every online Japanese dictionary that I know of provides reading, unless you mean something out of the ordinary by "reading." Take the following entry from [WWWJDIC](http://wwwjdic.mygengo.com/cgi-data/wwwjdic?1C) for reference:

> 結論 【けつろん】 (n,vs,adj-no) conclusion; (P)

**Edit:** [WWWJDIC](http://wwwjdic.mygengo.com/cgi-data/wwwjdic?1C) also contains audio examples for many common words, as Lukman points out in [his answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/i-am-looking-for-an-online-japanese-dictionary-with-audio-pronunciations/2099#2099).

Comment: I mean pronunciations, the sound.

Answer (score 4):

UmaiKanji has an [audio library](http://umaikanji.com/Library). It doesn't have anywhere near as many words as a dictionary, so don't expect to get a result for every word you look up. It's not a dictionary actually, but with Rikaikun/chan its useful.

I've seen dictionaries on the iPhone that use software to synthesize the readings.

Apple and Microsoft do this decently (for words more than sentences), in English at least. So, desktop software in combination with the OS's text-to-speech, or some dictionary that can take advantage of their frameworks is a possible lead for you.

Answer (score 4):

I use http://nihongoresources.com which includes a lot grammar and pronunciation as well as a dictionary.

Comment: Also, I use google.com/translate and you can then listen to the reading. It is not very good quality, however. It is best to learn the basics of the kana and their readings.

Comment: Google Translate uses a very high quality (perhaps current state of the art) speech synthesizer. So while it's very good for a robot, it's not the same as actual recordings because it doesn't get everything right by any stretch.

Answer (score 1):

I've yet to see a dictionary that didn't provide the reading.  Plus, if you did manage to find one, you could just install RikaiChan or RikaiKun (depending on your browser) and it would give you the reading.

Comment: For what it’s worth, English-Japanese dictionaries for Japanese speakers (who speak English as a foreign language) usually do not provide readings of words in Japanese.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I use Nihongo de Care-navi for Japanese pronunciation with audio. It is actually not a dictionary, but it is for nurses and doctors in Japan to learn English. It however contains a large enough vocabulary that most of the everyday Japanese words are included. It also includes variations of a same word.

http://eng.nihongodecarenavi.jp/jpn/search-list.php?cmd=search&q=%E8%A8%AA%E5%95%8F

Answer (score 0):

I run Jlearn which is a fairly comprehensive Online Japanese dictionary and has audio for all words and readings for kanji.

http://jlearn.net

Answer (score 0):

Throughout my searches I find the some of the best audio practice to Japanese youtube video's with subtitles - though, of course, they may not always be right.

Also free online TTS systems could work but their syntax is often strange. I like https://acapela-box.com/AcaBox/index.php the best.

Or for those who are pretty beginner then of course you could use the audio flashcards I just developed on my site. (Sorry for the shameless plug, it fit lol)